# Bicoloured 2048

Tags: strategy, video-games

I made a new puzzle game that you can play [here](https://dimkadimon.github.io/2048Multi/). It is a variant of [2048](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2048_(video_game)) where there are tiles of two colours. You need to merge tiles of the same colour and value to increase your score. In more detail, the rules are as follows:

1. You can shift all the tiles in one of the four directions (left, right, up or down). The tiles will slide until they hit the edge of the grid.
2. if two tiles with the same value $v$ slide into each other then they will will merge into a single tile with value $2v$ and you will earn $2v$ points.
3. After each move, a new tile will appear in a random empty location. The new tile will be either 2 or 3, chosen at random with equal probability.
4. The game ends when all 16 tiles are on the board and there are no more moves to make them merge.

Here is a screenshot of the game:

[image]

I am yet to find a good strategy for this game. It seems that you cannot use the same strategy as in 2048 - build large values in one corner. This is because the second colour gets in the way. So I am wondering what is the highest score possible? The best I have achieved so far is 968.

Comment: "What is a good strategy" seems extremely vague, and correct answers will be based on opinion. Also, this question does not seem like it relates to puzzles in any way.

Comment: Well the question is about a puzzle. I am looking for a general strategy that guarantees a high expected score in this game. I realise this is a little open-ended. However, we had questions like this in the past about the original 2048. The second question is more specific - what is the maximum score possible?

Comment: 2048 is not a puzzle; there's no "solution". You can make a puzzle that involves the game of 2048, but I don't think 2048 by itself constitutes a puzzle. Also, you should remove the part of your question that is "open-ended", as you put it - otherwise, it seems to me that it should be closed as subjective.

Comment: Done. Just keeping the second question. The highest score possible is a single finite answer. It can be found theoretically or experimentally.

Comment: ^vote with a note: fun game alright but it could/should be described more completely here, perhaps including a picture or two

Comment: @humn good point. I've added a screenshot and detailed description of the rules. Please let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: Thank you @humn! I am glad you like it. I am also addicted and even dream about it. I still struggle to find a good strategy that guarantees a high score. There seems to be a lot of luck involved. My friend who is a great player of the original game is also struggling. Two of my other friends have almost achieved 1200, which you can see on the leaderboard. Let me know what your best result is. I am also planning to write my own solver for this game. It will be based on random simulations.

Comment: Well done @humn. That score makes you third in the World!

Comment: New world record :)) https://imgur.com/a/Gh8aL2f

Comment: Wow great work @daw! Unfortunately I need to disappoint you - someone now got 1510. You are still second and can capture the lead.

Comment: are you looking for the general strategy or a max points?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I would love to see both of those answered. They are related anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I decided to investigate this problem myself, since I am the one who created it. The best score found by anyone is currently 1510. My own best score is 1314. Next I wanted to see if this score can be improved with automated methods.

First I wrote a random game simulator. The simulator simply takes random moves (in any 4 directions). After 1 million games the simulator was able to find 888 with an average score of 183. Running it for 12 million games it managed to find 1070, but this is still far from human-level performance. I then noticed something interesting. If you restrict the simulator to just 3 directions (I used down, left and right) then it tends to find higher scores. The new simulator finds 1226 after 1 million games with a somewhat lower average of 177. In fact I noticed this strategy myself during manual play, by focusing on just 3 directions I found that you are more likely to build bigger tiles, which always stay at the bottom. It is also easier to play as you only need to consider a few possible moves. This is how I got my top score of 1314. After 34 million runs, the new simulator reached 1440, which is approaching the best human play.

But I wanted to get higher scores, so this is what I did. For each available move, run the 3-directional simulator for 1000 games from that point onward. Then pick the move that obtained the highest average score. This now gives us look-ahead and makes a decent AI bot. After running this bot many times for 1 week it managed to get a score of **3060**. The final board position looked like this:

```
   3   2   3   2
   2   6  32   6
  32  24  96  64
   3 128 192   3
```

You can see that it managed to obtain both the 128 and the 192 tiles. I still feel that larger tiles could be possible, but this is quite good. Note that the bot is playing with the same input as what the human gets - ie., it does not know where the new tiles will appear. I managed to store how the game progressed and you can see it all [here](https://pastebin.com/kdb9W6vG). Each move is shown on a separate grid. I wish I could make a video out of it, but not sure how to do that.

I am interested if anyone can beat this score with human or computer play?

Update 11/05/2023: After many people have played this game for a considerable amount of time, the best human score is 2568. This is very high, but still behind the 3060 obtained by the bot.

Answer (score 3):

For the maximum score:

On observation:

> The board always starts with a 2 and a 3. So if the new block always spawns a 3, only 15 tiles are available for the 3-blocks (including the one from initial setup).

Doing the math:

> We will assume that the 3-blocks always spawn since they make the maximum tile possible.
>  Scoring:
>       - Creating a $3$-tile will score 0 points.
>       - Creating a $6$-tile will score $(3 + 3)*1 = 6$ points.
>       - Creating a $12$-tile will score $(3 + 3)*2 + (6 + 6)*1 = 24$ points.
>       - Creating a $24$-tile will score $(3 + 3)*4 + (6 + 6)*2 + (12 + 12)*1 = 72$ points.
>
>  On simplification:
>       - $3(2^0)$-tile = $0*3 = 0$
>       - $3(2^1)$-tile = $1*6 = 6$
>       - $3(2^2)$-tile = $2*12 = 24$
>       - $3(2^3)$-tile = $3*24 = 72$
>  Giving us the equation $3(2^n) = (3n)(2^n)$.
>
>  Finding the maximum tile:
>      - On observation we found that 15 tiles are available.
>      - Evaluating our expression $3(2^n)$ as $n = 15 - 1$ (since our tile starts with a 0 exponent) gives us 49152.
>
>  Our theoretical board will have all tiles like this (16 total):
>    `2, 49152, 24576, ..., 12, 6, 3` (Note the 2 on the initial setup!)
>
>  Putting the scores:
>    $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{14}(3n)(2^{n}) = 1277958$$

Comment: Very nice! So this would be the absolute maximum if you only got all 3. This is very unlikely and most games it is hard to score above 500.